# Get int value from picker using dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, xamarin

Somebody told me that the key of a dictionary should be unique, so i changed my dictionary from:

```
    Dictionary<string, int> recipients = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

to

```
    Dictionary<int, string> recipients = new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

Because the int is unique in my case, and the string isn't per se.

But first i could get the int from a picker aswell, but now i cant figure it out.

The picker:

```
    pickerRecipients = new Picker
        {
        };
        foreach (string recipientName in recipients.Values)
        {
            pickerRecipients.Items.Add(recipientName);
        }
```

First i would do

```
    string currentlySelected = pickerRecipients.Items[pickerRecipients.SelectedIndex];
```

But now it obviously doesnt work, but i can't find a way to get the int (the picker shows the string, which is a name, the int thats connected to it is an unique user number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// get the key of the first match
var key = recipients.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == selectedName).Key;
```

Comment: Thanks (: Jason saves the day again

Comment: to be fair, this is exactly the answer @Ehsan gave you on your previous question

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to put it as a comment but your code will have problems. For example if u have this values in your dictionary : '1 someValue', '2 otherValue', '3 someValue' and the user will pick '3 someValue'. Your code will return 1. 
I think you could try to insert (I entered a SPACE before the ( so i can split by ' ')

```
foreach (var recipient in recipients)
{
     pickerRecipients.Items.Add(recipient.Value + " (" + recipient.Key + ")");
}
```

then get the user selected value with

```
string currentlySelected = pickerRecipients.Items[pickerRecipients.SelectedIndex];
```

split the result like

```
var selectedIndex = currentlySelected.Split(' ').Last().Split('(', ')')[1];
```

and you get your selected index.
Again, this is not a direct solution to your problem but your problem will generate other problems if you don't take this into consideration.